# Should I have to open a docx file to be able to search about a specific string in it?

Tags: python, docx

I am trying write a program to be able to search about some strings in some docx files, should I open these docx files first to be able to search in them or the mission can be done without?

Comment: Yes, of course. You will need to do it using some third-party module because Python cannot natively open them (in a way to make searching through them work properly).

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier if you opened it first. I'm pretty sure this can be done with the `pandas` module.